How did “way to go” come to mean “well done”?
The idiomatic expression “way to go” used as an exclamation of approval appears to have been first used  in sports and later as a general  set phrase.
How did the literal  meaning “way to go” acquire the figurative sense? Literally it seems to suggest “still a long way ahead”, hardly an expression  of achievement.
So, how did this turn in meaning arise?

What makes you think that sports is the origin?

@LPH - it is in the link from Dictionary.com

I've always assumed it's truncated from That is/was the [right] way to go (or ...a good way to go / way to do it or whatever). Whatever - someone else says It's short for "That's the way to go!" - meaning, roughly, "What you did was a good thing to do.

Imno it's essentially AmE. Many decades ago in BrE we used the "catchphrase" "That's the way to do it!" in a similar fashion.

"way" has multiple meanings. It seems here it means rather direction than distance, hence "this is the right way" meaning

In the OED, we find way to go related to sports’ that’s the way to go in there (Al Klasoskus was a New York Giants football player):

way noun1 & interjection1
P.5.f. Originally and chiefly North American. way to go: expressing approval, support, admiration; ‘well done’. 1950–
[earliest attestation] [1942   As they
point out, it is much easier to shout ‘Atta way to go there, Jonesy,
old boy.’ Instead of ‘That's the way to go in there, Klasoskus.’
—Daily Ardmoreite (Ardmore, Oklahoma) 2 September 8/1]*
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login
required)

*brackets around an entire quotation indicates that a quotation is relevant to the development of a meaning but not directly illustrative of it.

Green’s Dictionary of Slang lists the exclamation way to go! as a short form of that’s the right way to go, noting that it may have been coined for the 1940 American biographical film Knute Rockne All American, which tells the story of Notre Dame's legendary football coach Knute Rockne.

way to go! excl. 
also way to be! 
[allegedly coined for the 1940 film Knute Rockne] 
an excl. of approval, i.e. that’s the right way to go. 
1966    [US]    J. Mills Panic in Needle Park (1971) 169: Helen threw her arms around Hotchner and gave him a hug. That drew a cheer and cries of ‘Way to go, Hotch!’ from other narcos in the hall.

